# How to export all package API names in GO

Tags: go

export to api.txt file,such as

```
fmt.Println(params...)
net.LookupIP(params...)
...
```

line by line

I using this to IDE autocomplete

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think this is a simple answer. Look at the [`ast` package](http://golang.org/pkg/go/ast/)? Also, why not just use [gocode](https://github.com/nsf/gocode)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, gocode may well do what you want already. But anyway, to list the exported API of a package you can use `go tool api <pkg>`. e.g.

```
$ go tool api runtime | grep func

pkg runtime, func Breakpoint()
pkg runtime, func CPUProfile() []byte
pkg runtime, func Caller(int) (uintptr, string, int, bool)
pkg runtime, func Callers(int, []uintptr) int
pkg runtime, func FuncForPC(uintptr) *Func
pkg runtime, func GC()
...
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already a text file with the full Go1 API in the go repository:
http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/api/go1.txt

But I recommend you to set up [gocode](https://github.com/nsf/gocode) (maybe by writing a small plugin for your IDE if there isn't any already). It provides context-sensitive auto-completion for variables and packages, even if they aren't part of the standard library or when they have been imported with a different name.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the package files, walk the TLDs, collect the exported and exposed identifiers, and you are almost where gocode is for years.